Google Picker API giving Null user before completing authorization
I am using the google picker api example code from https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample and when I tried authenticating with google, it always gives me back a null access token before I even complete the authorization part. Here is the following code I used for authorizing:
let tokenClient;
let accessToken = null;
let pickerInited = false;
let gisInited = false;


document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

/**
 * Callback after api.js is loaded.
 */
function gapiLoaded() {
  gapi.load('client:picker', initializePicker);
}
/**
 * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
 * discovery doc to initialize the API.
 */
async function initializePicker() {
   
  await gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest');
  pickerInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

/**
 * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
 */
function gisLoaded() {
  tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    callback: '', // defined later
  });
  gisInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

/**
 * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
 */
function maybeEnableButtons() {
  if (pickerInited && gisInited) {
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

/**
 *  Sign in the user upon button click.
 **/
function handleAuthClick() {
  tokenClient.callback = async (response) => {
    if (response.error !== undefined) {
      throw (response);
    }
    accessToken = response.access_token;
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
    await createPicker();
  };

  if (accessToken === null) {
    // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
    // when establishing a new session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
  } else {
    // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
  }
  console.log(tokenClient);
}

/**
 *  Sign out the user upon button click.
 */
function handleSignoutClick() {
  if (accessToken) {
    accessToken = null;
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(accessToken);
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

/**
 *  Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
 */
function createPicker() {
  console.log("Create Picker");
  const view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
  view.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg');
  const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
      .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
      .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
      .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
      .setAppId(APP_ID)
      .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
      .addView(view)
      .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
      .setCallback(pickerCallback)
      .build();
  picker.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Displays the file details of the user's selection.
 * @param {object} data - Containers the user selection from the picker
 */
async function pickerCallback(data) {
  if (data.action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    let text = `Picker response: \n${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}\n`;
    const document = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
    const fileId = document[google.picker.Document.ID];
    console.log(fileId);
    const res = await gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      'fileId': fileId,
      'fields': '*',
    });
    text += `Drive API response for first document: \n${JSON.stringify(res.result, null, 2)}\n`;
    window.document.getElementById('content').innerText = text;
  }
}

From this, I get the popupp to log into my google account but the picker does not show up after I complete my login and when I added another button to forcefully build the picker, I get error 403 saying they dont have access to the page. It also seems that the await createPicker(); is never called
I tried moving around async tag in my function but nothing could stop the function from continuing and giving me a null user. I am hosting this on a Django server and I am trying to use OAuth2. I also tried tinkering with the redirect URI in the google console which is currently set to http://127.0.0.1:8000 as my authorized javascript origin and http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback as my authorized redirect URI. It seems the tokenClient.callback = async (response) => { is never running as well so any ideas why would be great! Any info/help is appreciated!
